# Working with SignalR, WebApi, and Services

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, signalr

I'm new to SignalR and have some questions about using it correctly in certain scenarios

For my application I'm using signalR to communicate to a client the status of an operation they submitted, while they wait for the final response. My code is structured as such:

1. User click a button in UI
2. A connection established between the client and the hub
3. A call is made to our Web Api
4. The Web Api makes a call to logic on our service layer
5. The service layer processes data through a foreach.
6. For each iteration, the hub send out a signal containing data update a progress bar in the UI

I've been able to achieve all this. But I had to setup a new type using GetHubContext to be able to call my signal method, because I can't work with the Hub object directly. Doing this doesn't allow me to send the signal a specific user because it's not known to the service layer, I'm only able to broadcast to all.

What pattern should I be using to achieve this? For my current setup it seems I would need to setup incoming connections with a group equal to their connectionId, communicate the connectionId to the various layers, and send a signal to that specific "group" as needed. Is this the best setup?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that the answer is yes, that seems to be the best setup. Please, read the answer to this question, I'd say this will help you with an example.

[SignalR - Sending a message to a specific user using (IUserIdProvider) *NEW 2.0.0*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19522103/signalr-sending-a-message-to-a-specific-user-using-iuseridprovider-new-2-0)

[Edit]

The key point is the mapping between the connectionId and the users. In your case it will depend on your implementation, I can't tell you the best way to handle it...

Also, a very good answer there talks about SendToUser tests here:

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/release/tests/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.FunctionalTests/Server/Hubs/HubFacts.cs

It lookjs like something you could use in your solution.
[Edit]

I hope it helps.