# signalR - send message to specific user

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

I'm working through the `SignalR` Microsoft tutorial located [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio).

Everything is working ok, however, I wanted to try to change the code in `ChatHub#SendMessage` to send a message to a specific user.

So I modified the code like this:

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
    {
        //await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);

        await Clients.User(user).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
    }
}
```

However, the user never gets the message.  The message is only sent if you use `Clients.All.SendAsync` (that's the line that's commented out above).

I also did more research and found from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51966231/how-to-user-iuseridprovider-in-net-core) that maybe I need to implement a custom user provider. So I implemented one:

```
public class CustomUserIdProvider : IUserIdProvider
{
    public string GetUserId(HubConnectionContext connection)
    {
        return "user1";
    }
}
```

Then in `Startup.cs`, I registered this provider:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddSingleton<IUserIdProvider, CustomUserIdProvider>();
    services.AddSignalR();
}
```

Then I tried using the `Context.UserIdentifier` when sending the message, like this:

```
public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
{
    //await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);

    await Clients.User(Context.UserIdentifier).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
}
```

But it still does not seem to send the message.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you looked in to this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections

Comment: @Andy- Thanks for the link, I did look into that one.  However, it's not for dotnet core unfortunately.

Comment: ah bummer.. I hate that. but some of it may transfer. I'll add an answer on how I handle users based on groups. Maybe it might be useful down the road.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue.  I'd left off the user parameter in the `Clients.User(user).SendAsync` call.

So it should be like this:

```
public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
{
    //await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);

    await Clients.User(user).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message); // <-- add user parameter
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This saved me. However my mistake was different.

Answer (score 3):

The way I do it is when a user logs in I add them to a SignalR Group, the Group being the user's ID or Name. that way it's a unique group for just that one user. Then I send the message to that Group. Only that user will get that message because they are the only one in that group.

Client Side Code:

```
// Optional: authenticate with a server, get a token... or send username/password in following request

_hub = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl(_envSettings.CreatePlayerServiceHubPath(), x =>
    {
        x.Headers.Add("x-lcc-version", AppEnvironment.Application.Version);
        x.Headers.Add("x-lcc-username", username);
        x.Headers.Add("x-lcc-authorization", token);
    })
    .AddNewtonsoftJsonProtocol()
    .Build();

_hub.Closed += OnSignalRDisconnectedFromServerAsync;
SetupRPCs();
await _hub.StartAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Server Side Code:

```
public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
{
    var userName = Context.GetHttpContext().Request.Headers["x-lcc-username"];
    var token = Context.GetHttpContext().Request.Headers["x-lcc-authorization"];
    
    // Optional: validate authorization
    
    await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, userName);
    
    // Then when you want to send a message to the user:
    await Clients.Group(userName).SendAsync("hello", "world");
}
```

What's nice is that when the user disconnects, the `Group` automatically disappears. You don't have to maintain those groups you are creating.

I know this may not be 100% what you are looking for, but it's an idea of how to handle similar situations with other scenarios.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info, I may end up using this idea at some point.