# How to send message to specific user in signalR Asp.net WebForms

Tags: asp.net, webforms, signalr

I also consulted the articles:

- [SignalR - Sending a message to a specific user using (IUserIdProvider) *NEW 2.0.0*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19522103/signalr-sending-a-message-to-a-specific-user-using-iuseridprovider-new-2-0)
- [signalR - send message to specific user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63303966/signalr-send-message-to-specific-user)
- [Send message to specific user in signalr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31130094/send-message-to-specific-user-in-signalr)

**I'm using signalR to chat with specific users in Asp.net WebForms**. My wishes are as follows:

- I have a list of users in the database. I display it using Repeater.
- When I click on that User it opens the message dialog `divChatWindow`
- In the message dialog (`divChatWindow`) I have 1 input + 1 button to send the message content.

When the button sends the message click
`$('#btsendmessenger').click(function()....` I call the event:

```
chatHub.server.sendPrivateMessage(toUserID, msg, datetext, userAvatar);
```

However, how do I know the value of `toUserID` ---> `//The person who received the message`

Here are the codes that I am using:

I have the following data pages:
**Chat.aspx**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
    <ContentTemplate>
        //User chat list displayed from database
        <ul id="_listus">
            <asp:Repeater ID="rptListChat" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li data-value='<%# Eval("Code") %>' data-user='<%# Eval("fromUserIDGet") %>'>   
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <img src='<%# Eval("fromUserAvatar") %>' class="p5 radius30">
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <div>
                                    <div class="font-600 text-15"><%# Eval("fromUser") %></div>
                                    <span class="font-500 text-13"><%# Eval("lastMessenge") %> <span class="text-10"><%# Eval("lastDayMessenge") %></span></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </ul>
        <asp:Button ID="btngetDetail" runat="server" OnClick="btngetDetail_Click" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="none" />
        
        //Div showing chat dialog
        <asp:Panel ID="pnDetailchat" runat="server" Visible="false">
          <div id="divChatWindow"></div>
          //Input to enter message content and send button
          <div>
               <div>
                   <asp:TextBox ID="_txtmessenger" AutoCompleteType="None" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="form_cmt__" />
               </div>
               <div id="btsendmessenger"><i class="las la-paper-plane"></i></div>
          </div>
        </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<input id="hdId" type="hidden" />
<input id="hdUserName" type="hidden" />
<input id="hdUserAvatar" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" type="hidden" />
```

**Javascript handling signalR**

```
<script src="scripts/jquery.signalR-2.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="signalr/hubs"></script>
<script>
    $("#_listus").on('click', 'li', function (e) {
        $('#btngetDetail').click();     
    });
</script>
<script>
    //On UpdatePanel Refresh
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    if (prm != null) {
        prm.add_endRequest(function (sender, e) {
            if (sender._postBackSettings.panelsToUpdate != null) {
                if (document.getElementById("pnDetailchat")) {
                    /*chat*/
                    $(function () {
                        // Declare a proxy to reference the hub. 
                        var chatHub = $.connection.chatHub;
                        registerClientMethods(chatHub);
                        // Start Hub
                        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                            registerEvents(chatHub)
                        });
                    });
                    function registerEvents(chatHub) {

                        var name = '<%= this.UserID %>';
                        if (name.length > 0) {
                            chatHub.server.connect(name);
                        }
                        $('#btsendmessenger').click(function () {

                            var msg = $("#_txtmessenger").val();
                            if (msg.length > 0 && msg.trim().replace(/'/g, '')) {
                                var userName = $('#hdUserName').val();
                                var userAvatar = $('#hdUserAvatar').val();
                                var date = new Date();
                                var datetext = date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes();                                    
                                $("#_txtmessenger").val('');
                                document.getElementById('_txtmessenger').focus();
                                AddMessage(userName, msg, datetext, userAvatar);

                                var toUserID = ...**//How to get ConnectionId of specific user for chat**
                                chatHub.server.sendPrivateMessage(toUserID, msg, datetext, userAvatar);
                            }
                            else {
                                document.getElementById('_txtmessenger').focus();
                                document.getElementById("_txtmessenger").value = "";
                            }
                        });

                        $("#_txtmessenger").keypress(function (e) {
                            if (e.which == 13) {
                                e.preventDefault();
                                $('#btsendmessenger').click();
                            }
                        });
                        document.getElementById('_txtmessenger').focus();
                    }
                    function registerClientMethods(chatHub) {

                        // Calls when user successfully logged in
                        chatHub.client.onConnected = function (id, userName, allUsers, messages, times) {
                            $('#hdId').val(id);
                            $('#hdUserName').val(userName);
                            // Add Existing Messages
                            for (i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                                AddMessage(messages[i].UserName, messages[i].Message, messages[i].Time, messages[i].UserImage);
                            }
                        }

                        chatHub.client.messageReceived = function (userName, message, time, userimg) {
                            AddMessage(userName, message, time, userimg);
                        }
                    }

                    function AddMessage(userName, message, time, userimg) {

                        var CurrUser = $('#hdUserName').val();
                        var Side = '_cusms left';
                        if (CurrUser == userName) {
                            Side = '_myms right';
                        }
                        var divChat =
                            '<div class="direct-chat-msg mb-20 ' + Side + '">' +
                            '<div class="flex gap10 item_chat_">' +
                            '<div class="w50">' +
                            '<img src="' + userimg + '" class="radius30 overflow-hidden">' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '<div class="flex-col w50per">' +
                            '<div class="info_us flex">' +
                            '<div class="font-600 text-14">' + userName + '</div>' +
                            '<div class="font-300 text-12">' + time + '</div>' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '<div class="_messenger">' + message + '</div>' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '</div >' +
                            '</div>';

                        $('#divChatWindow').append(divChat);

                        var height = $('#divChatWindow')[0].scrollHeight;
                        $('#divChatWindow').scrollTop(height);

                    }
                }
            }
        });
    };
</script>
```

**Chat.aspx.cs**

```
public string UserID = "";
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadInfoUser();
    LoadListChatUs();
}
protected void LoadInfoUser()
{
    string getuserid = "Select ....";
    DataTable dtgetuserid = XLDL.ReadDb(getuserid);
    ...
    {
        UserID = dtgetuserid.Rows[0]["UserID"].ToString();
    }
}
protected void LoadListChatUs()
{
    string getlistchat = "Select ....";
    DataTable getlistchat = XLDL.ReadDb(getlistchat);
    ...
    {
        rptListChat.DataSource = getlistchat;
        rptListChat.DataBind();
    }
}
protected void btngetDetail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pnDetailchat.Visible = true;
}
```

**ChatHub.cs**

```
public void Connect(string userID)
{
    userid = userID;    
    var id = Context.ConnectionId;
    if (ConnectedUsers.Count(x => x.ConnectionId == id) == 0)
    {
        string logintime = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        ConnectedUsers.Add(new Users
        {
            ConnectionId = id,
            UserName = userName,
            UserImage = imgavatar
        });

        // send to caller
        Clients.Caller.onConnected(id, userName, ConnectedUsers, CurrentMessage);

        // send to all except caller client
        Clients.AllExcept(id).onNewUserConnected(id, userName, imgavatar, logintime);
    }
}
public void SendPrivateMessage(string toUserId, string message, string time, string userAvatar)
{
    string fromUserId = Context.ConnectionId;
    var toUser = ConnectedUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ConnectionId == toUserId);
    var fromUser = ConnectedUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ConnectionId == fromUserId);
    if (toUser != null && fromUser != null)
    {
        // send to
        Clients.Client(toUserId).sendPrivateMessage(fromUserId, fromUser.UserName, message, time, userAvatar);
        // send to caller user
        Clients.Caller.sendPrivateMessage(toUserId, fromUser.UserName, message, time, userAvatar);
    }

}
```

**Assume an online user in the user list can receive a real-time message when the event $('#btsendmessenger').click(function()....to a specific user.
I'm pretty vague about the value of var toUserID = ?**

Looking forward to everyone's help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think first you check the users who are online. Then check that user the corresponding account in the list of users from the DB displayed in the Repeater or not. If there is a corresponding hungwsuser append

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).