# ASP.NET Core Angular - send different SignalR messages based on logged in user

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, signalr, identityserver4

I have Angular SPA ASP.NET Core app with Identity (**IdentityServer4**). I use SignalR to push real-time messages to clients.

However I have to "broadcast" messages. All clients receive same messages regardless of what they require and then they figure out in Typescript - do they need this message or not.

What I want is to be able to decide which SignalR client should receive message and what content - it will make messages shorter and cut out processing time on clients completely.

I see there is `hub.Client.User(userId)` method - thats what I need.. However it appears that the Identity user ID is not known to SignalR.

If I override `public override Task OnConnectedAsync()` - context inside doesnt have any useful information eg user/principals/claims - are empty.

How can I find out which `IdentityServer4` user is connecting to the hub?

**EDIT1** suggested implementing IUserIdProvider doesnt work - all xs are null.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-5.0#use-claims-to-customize-identity-handling

```
public string GetUserId(HubConnectionContext connection)
{
    var x1 = connection.User?.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email)?.Value;
    var x2 = connection.User?.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
    var x3 = connection.User?.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value;
...
```

**EDIT2** implemented "Identity Server JWT authentication" from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-5.0 - doesnt work either - `accessToken` is empty in `PostConfigure`

Comment: Maybe check if the signalR hub is mapped (MapHub method or something) after your authentication middleware

Comment: it is mapped...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an obvious solution to it. Here is the sample one can use after creating an asp.net core angular app with identity.

*Note that in this particular scenario (Angular with ASP.NET Core with Identity) you do **NOT** need to implement anything else, in contrary to multiple suggestions from people mis-reading the doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-5.0*

Client side:

```
import { AuthorizeService } from '../../api-authorization/authorize.service';

. . .

constructor(. . . , authsrv: AuthorizeService) {

  this.hub = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("/newshub", { accessTokenFactory: () => authsrv.getAccessToken().toPromise() })
    .build();
```

Server side:

```
[Authorize]
public class NewsHub : Hub
{
    public static readonly SortedDictionary<string, HubAuthItem> Connected = new SortedDictionary<string, HubAuthItem>();

    public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        NewsHub.Connected.Add(Context.ConnectionId, new HubAuthItem
        {
            ConnectionId = Context.ConnectionId,
            UserId = Context.User?.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value
        });

        return base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
if(NewsHub.Connected.Count != 0)
    foreach (var cnn in NewsHub.Connected.Values.Where(i => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(i.UserId)))
        if(CanSendMessage(cnn.UserId)
            hub.Clients.Users(cnn.UserId).SendAsync("servermessage", "message text");
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement [IUserIdProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.iuseridprovider?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and register it in the services collection.

Check this question - [How to user IUserIdProvider in .NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51966231/how-to-user-iuseridprovider-in-net-core)

Comment: it is not working for me. In the `GetUserId` I have exactly same `context` object as I already have in `OnConnectedAsync` with empty User data. I dont know how to find out which user has connected or else I wouldnt need `GetUserId`. The only piece of data I have is `connectionId`.. I just need to find a way to correlate it with userId.

Comment: Well, I'm out of ideas. Does non-SignalR authentication work as expected? Normal controllers?

Comment: yeah.. i am going to make new question. i just did out of the box microsoft template angular app and added signalr. nothing else. auth doesnt work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68614232/signalr-authorization-not-working-out-of-the-box-in-asp-net-core-angular-spa-wit

Answer (score 0):

It is transpired that User data is empty in SignalR server context because authorization doesnt work as I expected it to. <s>To implement SignalR authorization with Identity Server seems to be a big deal and is a security risk as it will impact the whole app - you essentially need to manually override huge amount of code which already is done by Identity Server just to satisfy SignalR case.</s>

So I came up with a **workaround**, see my answer to myself here:

[SignalR authorization not working out of the box in asp.net core angular SPA with Identity Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68614232/signalr-authorization-not-working-out-of-the-box-in-asp-net-core-angular-spa-wit)

EDIT: I missed an obvious solution - see the other answer. This is still valid workaround though, so I am going to let it hang here.