# SignalR Core - GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register

Tags: c#, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm trying to map SignalR Users to connections using IUserIdProvider as mentioned in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21355406/750216

How can I run `GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IUserIdProvider), () => idProvider);` inside `Startup.Configure(...)`?

The issue is that `GlobalHost` is [no longer available in SignalR core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and I don't think it is possible to inject a `IHubContext` service into `Startup` class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to add `services.AddSingleton<IUserIdProvider, CustomUserIdProvider>();` to `Startup.ConfigureServices(...)` instead.