# SignalR Irequest User is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, signalr

I followed this answer but Im getting Null in Irequest request.User

[SignalR - Sending a message to a specific user using (IUserIdProvider) *NEW 2.0.0*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19522103/signalr-sending-a-message-to-a-specific-user-using-iuseridprovider-new-2-0/21355406#21355406)

I created a class in app_start folder like this

```
public class CustomUserIdProvider : IUserIdProvider
    {
        public string GetUserId(IRequest request)
        {
            // your logic to fetch a user identifier goes here.

            // for example:

            var userId = request.User.Identity.Name;
            return userId.ToString();
        }
    }
```

After this I initialize new costom provider in Startup.cs like this :

```
 public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var idProvider = new CustomUserIdProvider();

            GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IUserIdProvider), () => idProvider);

            // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here
            app.MapSignalR();
         }
```

But Im getting exception on line

```
var userId = request.User.Identity.Name;
```

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

Comment: make sure your user is authenticated, otherwise User property will be always null.

Comment: No, login works fine.. I use User.Identity.Name on many other locations.. but it seems this is not same type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found issue, 
I had to initialize at end of startup.cs

```
app.MapSignalR();
```